# What is the best practice for keeping a background task running inside the Cloud Service application domain?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, signalr

I running a Windows Azure Cloud Service. I need a background task constantly running inside my Cloud Service application domain, so a extenal worker role isn't an option. This is because I need to notify JavaScript clients about certain events and I can only do that from inside my AppDomain. I need to make sure this task is **always** running, otherwise my service won't work properly.

So far my idea is to create a Thread in the application start and keep it running forever, but I don't know if it's the better idea.

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

THe reason why I can't use Worker Roles is that I need to be in the same application domain as the Cloud Service so I can notify clients through [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) connections.

Comment: A worker role is continually running, *why* is this not an option?

Comment: Have you considered Azure Notification Hub? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj927170.aspx

Comment: @PeterRitchie, thanks for the response. I updated the question with more details. AS for the Azure Notifications Hubs, I'm using SignalR, that is a standard solution and seems to be best suited to notify JavaScript clients.

Comment: I would think you'd run your background task as you'd do it with any other Windows Server app, since a Web Role (or worker Role) instance is just a Windows Server 2012 VM with some scaffolding code. A thread works fine, and you'd just need to have some mechanism for respawning if something causes the thread to die.

Comment: Seems like an unusual requirement. How are the events that you need to notify the client about performed? Why can't you notify from those events?

Answer (score 0):

In the same asp.net webapplication where you host SignalR, espose a wcf (svc) service or asmx web service and call it from your "h24 service". Now you can host your h24-service in a Worker Role or in a windows service (in a windows virtual machine).
PS: Remember to protect your svc or asmx from unwanted calls from internet ;)